# How to make a text rise or wave in either css or javascript (no animation)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make some dynamic text look like this in HTML:

[image: To make it look like this]
I don't mind if it's done in CSS or Javascript.
It's not supposed to animate in any way.

Comment: Is SVG an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faking it with CSS transforms:

```js
Math.easeInOutSine = function (t, b, c, d) {
  return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
};
var easing = Math.easeInOutSine,
    $target = $('#target'),
    position = $target.position(),
    width = $target.width(),
    height = 100;
$target.html($target.text().split('').map(
  function(char){
    return '<span>'+char+'</span>';
  }
).join(''));
var $chars = $target.children();
$chars.each(function(){
  var $char = $(this),
      w = $char.width(),
      l = $char.position().left,
      offset = easing(l, 0, height, width),
      skew = offset - easing(w + l, 0, height, width),
      angle = Math.atan(skew/w) * 180 / Math.PI;
  offset = -offset;
  $char.css({
    transform: 'translateY('+offset+'px) skewY('+angle+'deg)'
  });
});
$target.css({
  paddingTop: height
});
```

```css
#target {
  white-space:pre;
  display:inline-block;
}
#target span {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><div id="target">This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.</div></div>
```

http://codepen.io/ouroborus/pen/mmbzje

I say faking it because the individual letters aren't curved. Essentially, the curve is broken up into linear segments such that they are as wide as the character that's placed there and so it only approximates the curve. This becomes more noticeable as the font size increases.

Comment: This is with out a doubt the best and prettiest solution. I will go with that.
Thank you for the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

using @Mike Diglio's answer we can do one better.

```js
var letterContainer = document.querySelector(".letters");

var letters = letterContainer.innerText;

letters = letters.split("");

letterContainer.innerText = "";

var offset = 0;

letters.forEach(function(letter, i){
  var wrap = document.createElement("span");
  wrap.innerText = letter;
  wrap.style.position = "relative";
  wrap.style.bottom = i+"px";
  wrap.style.transform = "rotate("+-i+"deg)";
  letterContainer.appendChild(wrap);
})
```

```html
<div class="letters">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

Now you just need to come up with a function that figures out the mapping for you.

Comment: It just look's to clunky compared to @Ouroborus solution. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get glyph data for arbitrary text with the [opentypejs](https://opentype.js.org/) library. Then draw the path to SVG with that data. Using the [warpjs](https://github.com/benjamminf/warpjs) library, you can use custom functions to distort svg into the desired format.

And you can see more examples from the link below.

https://bluewings.github.io/en/playing-with-fonts/

---

Here is an example of drawing a text waving in svg.

```js
opentype.load(
  'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v13/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_c5H3gnD-A.woff',
  (err, font) => {
    const glyphs = font.stringToGlyphs('DEVELOPER');
    const { width, yValues, svgPath } = glyphs.reduce(
      (prev, glyph) => {
        const d = glyph.path.commands.map(({ type, x1, y1, x, y }) => {
          switch (type) {
            case 'M':
            case 'L':
              return `${type} ${x + prev.width} ${y}`;
            case 'Q':
              return `${type} ${x1 + prev.width} ${y1} ${x +
                prev.width} ${y}`;
            default:
              return type;
          }
        });
        return {
          svgPath: `${prev.svgPath}<path d="${d.join('')}" />`,
          width: prev.width + glyph.advanceWidth,
          yValues:
            typeof glyph.yMax !== 'number'
              ? prev.yValues
              : [...prev.yValues, glyph.yMax, glyph.yMin],
        };
      },
      { svgPath: '', width: 0, yValues: [] },
    );
    const yMax = Math.max(...yValues);
    const yMin = Math.min(...yValues);
    const height = yMax - yMin;

    const period = width;
    const amplitude = height / 2;

    const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height + amplitude * 2}`);
    svg.innerHTML = `<g transform="translate(0,${yMax +
      amplitude}) scale(1 -1)">${svgPath}</g>`;

    const warp = new Warp(svg);
    warp.transform(([x, y]) => [
      x,
      y + amplitude * Math.sin((x / period) * Math.PI * 2),
    ]);
    
    document.getElementById('example').appendChild(svg);
  },
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/warpjs@1.0.8/dist/warp.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/opentype.js/1.1.0/opentype.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe there are a few different methods to accomplish what you are looking for.

1. Depending on the length of the word, you could wrap each letter of the word in a `span` and assign each `span` a `class` so you can manipulate each individual letter. It doesn't look pretty in the markup, and when it comes to responsiveness (depending on the length of the word) or where you will be placing it, you can run into some issues. (You can see an example for that [HERE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t7p8h86f/))

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.h {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
.e {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
.l {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
.el {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 7px;
  transform: rotate(-9deg);
}
.o {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-11deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="h">H</span>
  <span class="e">E</span>
  <span class="l">L</span>
  <span class="el">L</span>
  <span class="o">O</span>
</div>
```

2. You can, as @Ouroborus suggested, use an SVG element and create a `path` and then move your text along that path in order to get your "curve" effect (You can checkout a link that goes into that [HERE](http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/196406a3486985d2b92e)
3. Another option is to use a JS library called [Lettering.JS](http://letteringjs.com/) - I haven't used this before, but there have been some recommendations for this across Stack Overflow and it does seem powerful (after a quick browse through the site)

Comment: You should include your code in the answer, not just link to it (having the link is fine)

Comment: @powerc9000 agree'd - added

Comment: This solution does not take into account that I asked for a solution for dynamic text. But thanks.